# How do i iterate over a group of objects in Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am confused about using Razor syntax to iterate over a group of objects.

Let's say in a Controller, I set:

```
            ViewBag.accounts = accounts;
            Session["accounts"] = accounts;
```

and in the cshtml page I would like to iterate over the accounts:

```
@foreach (var account in ViewBag.accounts)
```

that works great, but the same syntax does not work for the session:

```
@foreach (var account in Session.accounts)
```

nor

```
@foreach (var account in Session["accounts"])
```

How do I iterate over a collection in the session?

Answer (score 4):

`Session` is not dynamic.
Instead, its indexer returns `object`.

To use it in a foreach loop, you must explicitly cast the value to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
@foreach (var account in (IEnumerable<SomeType>)Session["accounts"])
```

Comment: IMO this is the job of the View Model, not the Session

Answer (score 3):

Using ViewData

ViewData is a dictionary of objects that are accessible using strings as keys. This means that we will write code like this:

**In the Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

var softwareDevelopers = new List<string>
{
    "Brendan Enrick", 
    "Kevin Kuebler", 
    "Todd Ropog"
};

ViewData["softwareDevelopers"] = softwareDevelopers;

return View();
```

}

**In the View**

```
<ul>
@foreach (var developer in (List<string>)ViewData["softwareDevelopers"])
{
<li>
    @developer
</li>
 }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I'd like to save you some pain.

As dwerner said, **this is a job for the ViewModel**, not the View.

The View should be as ignorant as possible of the environment its running in. It should ideally be aware of just: (1) The ViewModel that its strongly bound to *(via the `@model` declaration)*, and (2) any HTML Helper functions that you've got in the app *(basically these are extention methods off `HtmlHelper<Tmodel>`)*

Your ViewModel should contain a `List<Account>` which you fill with whatever `ViewBag.accounts` was, and then you can ignore Viewbag entirely. In your View, the collection is off the appropriate type ("Account") so you can interact with the Account objects directly in the `foreach` loop without casting back from `Object` or dealing with `Dynamics`.

Having "dumb" Views and "skinny" controllers keeps the bulk of your logic in the ViewModels, which are much cleaner and easier to maintain.